# Android Location Client not as Accurate as Google Maps App

Tags: android, google-maps, location-client

I want to preface this by saying that I'm in China where Google location services sometimes have issues.

I'm using the `LocationClient` to get user's current location.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
  ...
}
```

Very straightforward.  Then in my `onConnected` callback, I get the location.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
  ...
}
```

The location I get back is always the same, but it is about ~500m away from my actual location.  GPS is enabled, although the icon indicating it is being used does not come on.  I am also on WiFi and have 3G.

When I open the actual Google Maps app, my location is perfectly accurate (unlike the location I get in my own app).  I also see the icon indicating GPS is being used.

*Questions*

1. What is the Google Map app doing differently to get a more accurate location and how do I do what they do?
2. If the wrong location I get back is always the same what does that mean?  Without overthinking too much, it is a truth of China that foreign map data companies have coordinates the are skewed off by a factor and they have to use a specific algorithm to correct for that difference; is the Google Maps app doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

China has a special dealing with GPS data, because the government force the related map producing company to add some bias.
I'm stuck with it for a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

When using the method 'getLastLocation()', it offers the best last known location stored by the Location. It is also in respect to what level of permission you have given the app in the manifest file.

Try using both:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

in your manifest file and see if it improves the accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have both of these permissions and tried it with COARSE removed as well.  From my understanding the LocationClient or LocationManager will use the most accurate location it is allowed to get based on available permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1 Google Maps updates location continually. Try following these inductions: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Ad. 2 getLastLocation probably retrieves last location stored when it is updated like in point 1. If it's not updated, you will just get the same value. Location object has time attached and you can see when it was received.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Actually after more testing we found that this indeed was an issue with locations in China being set off by a factor, we tested in a few other countries and didn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. turn on the Satellite view. The normal "vector" view is obfuscated in China. For some reason, the Google Maps app doesn't have this issue.
2. the location returned by the GPS is correct, even in China (considering a WGS84 projection). Only the maps are not.

Other maps providers like [Baidu](http://developer.baidu.com/map/geosdk-android.htm) force you to use their own custom implementation of LocationClient. This way you get locations ready to be used on their map tiles.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but this hasn't been said:

You can set the accuracy of the locationClient, using the locationRequest.
E.g.

```
      mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
      mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
      mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, (LocationListener) this);
```

You can also set the frequency of updates.  If you need something highly precise, take a bunch of readings over a few seconds.  Then look at the "accuracy" number on each reading.  Toss out any readings whose accuracy is significantly less accurate than the others.  Then average the rest...

That's a pretty basic algorithm, and i'm getting accuracy within 1-2 feet on a galaxy S5 in the US.

If you use lower accuracy, it's going to average gps data with wifi and cellular results. GPS consumes more battery, so it uses it less often on this setting.  Wifi uses a physical address lookup, since its always moving me towards the public road near my house, even when I'm in the middle of it.

Comment: Thanks - this is definitely very helpful and a good thing to know. In the case of china though, it really is the Chinese government not allowing non-chinese companies to hold accurate maps, so there is a consistent and predictable offset.